# PDO bindvalue и переменные в Array

Tags: php, pdo

Хочу биндить переменные в массиве, но как совместить переменные запроса и параметры запроса в одном массиве и возможно ли это?

```
$name = 'Mike';
$limit = 2;

$user_data = [
    'name' => $name,
    'limit' => $limit
];

$stm = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=:name LIMIT :limit");
$stm -> execute($user_data);
$result = $stm->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row){
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

Таким образом не выводится ничего, даже ошибки. Проблема именно в параметре LIMIT. Если его прописать руками, то всё будет работать, но возможно ли его прописать в массиве $user_data ?

Comment: Это должно работать. Включите отображение ошибок, возможно оно не включено  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482   ............. а что внутри $result в итоге лежит?

Comment: Это не будет работать ибо в [мануале](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-parameters) сказано "Все значения будут приняты, как имеющие тип __PDO::PARAM_STR__. ". Остается только `bindValue` с `PDO::PARAM_INT`. Либо манипуляции с `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`

Comment: @u_mulder  ну или переходить на `?`

Comment: я правильно понимаю что либо переменные в array либо bindValue и то и то нельзя использовать?

Comment: Ну открой уже руководство почитай https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-description

Comment: Там нет ответа на мой вопрос, по этому и пишу. И в интернете не нашёл примеров, где через массив задаются и переменные запроса и limit. Везде идут отдельно плейсхолдеры либо в переменных либо в лимите. Тогда вопрос другой. Я понимаю зачем нужно PDO и preparing запросы, но на сколько нужно задавать лимиты через эти плейсхолдеры, это что тоже не безопасно?